# "detail": "Not found." in Django rest-api

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I got the error `"detail": "Not found."` even though some ids still works.

#### model.py

```py
class Profile(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    swipe = models.ForeignKey(Swipe, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    age = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=10, null=True)
    native_lan = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    foreign_lan = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30, null=True)
    time_start = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    time_end = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    intro = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    freeday = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=10, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

#### views.py

```py
class MyProfileView(GenericAPIView, RetrieveModelMixin,
CreateModelMixin, UpdateModelMixin, DestroyModelMixin, ListModelMixin):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    lookup_field = 'id'

    def post(self, request):
        return  self.create(request)
        
    def get(self, request, id=None):
        if id:
            user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
            profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=user)
            print(profile.id)

            return self.retrieve(request, profile.id)
        else:
            return self.list(request)

    def put(self, request, id=None):
        print('REQUEST::',request.FILES)
        return self.update(request, id)

    def delete(self, request, id=None):
        return self.destroy(request, id)
```

#### urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('list/', MyProfileView.as_view()),
    path('create/', MyProfileView.as_view()),
    path('update/<int:id>/', MyProfileView.as_view()),
    path('detail/<int:id>/', MyProfileView.as_view()),
    path('delete/<int:id>/', MyProfileView.as_view()),
]
```

[image: all the profiles]

My expectation is that you get user by the id of user account and it allows you to get id of profile, finally returning the profile.

But, when I put `id=2` which is the id of user account, I got `"detail": "Not found."` despite that I confirmed `profile.id=1` by printing it out.
One more thing that I don't understand is when I put `id=3`, I got the profile correctly.

How do I fix that?
Thank you:)

Comment: You don't need to define ```id``` field.It is created automatically.  Regarding your question, did you verify that Profile with ```id==2``` actually exists? You can check this using ```python manage.py shell``` Then ```from yourApp.models import Profile``` then ```Profile.objects.filter(id=2).exists()``` . If it gives True then object exists else not.

Comment: It might be user role permissions issue.

Comment: I deleted database and remade it. but I couldn't fix it.  My problem is  for example, when the id of A's account is 1 and the id of A's profile is 2, I want to get A's profile in the state that I only have A's account id(1). if I pass  /detail/1/, I just got the profile id of which is 1 not 2.

Comment: @Amandeep Singh Sawhney I deleted lookup_field and I changed <int:id> to <int:pk> but I got the above problem

Comment: Maybe I can't use GenericAPIView in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. In this case, GenericAPIView does not allow you to customize your get mothod this way, so you need to make functional methods or other class methods.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_profile(request, pk):
    print(pk)
    if pk:
        user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
        profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=user)
        serializer =ProfileSerializer(profile)


        return Response(serializer.data)
```